# How do I make items in scroll-list clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, list

How do I make the list items(bananas, oranges, and so on) clickable?

So I want to click on kiwi and make it to go to page kiwi.html or so

http://jsfiddle.net/pr6tvsxm/

```
<select name="fruit" size="4" multiple>
    <option selected> Apples</option>
    <option> Bananas</option>
    <option> Oranges</option>
    <option> Watermelon</option>
    <option> Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<SELECT id="sel" NAME="fruit" SIZE="4" MULTIPLE >
<OPTION SELECTED> Apples
<OPTION value="Bananas.html"> Bananas                                                                         
<OPTION value="Oranges.html"> Oranges
<OPTION value="Watermelon.html"> Watermelon
<OPTION value="Kiwi.html"> Kiwi
</SELECT>
```

and your javascript

```
document.getElementById("sel").onclick = function(d){
  window.location = this.value;
};
```

updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pr6tvsxm/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<SELECT NAME="fruit" SIZE="4" MULTIPLE onchange="goToPage(this)">
<OPTION SELECTED> Apples
<OPTION> Bananas 
<OPTION> Oranges
<OPTION> Watermelon
<OPTION> Kiwi
</SELECT>

<script>
function goToPage(select) {
    var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    window.location.href = value + ".html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I really didn't see your answer before write mine own. I see that is very similar

Answer (score 1):

You can't use href inside option tags. Try using onchange ettribute to run some javascript

```
<select MULTIPLE  onchange="goToPage(this)">
<option value="test.html">Banana</option>
<option value="test2.html">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

and then

```
function goToPage(element)
{
window.location = element.value;
}
```

Comment: I just want to remind you to add the `multiple` attribute to the `<select>` element.

Comment: Inline event handling is bad coding practice. Abstract the code for easier readability and maintainability

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a list of links if you want them to go to another page?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="somewhere.com">Apples</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.com">Bananas</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.com">Oranges</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.com">Watermelon</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.com">Kiwi</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even if this is better(it is), it doesn't answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `change` event.

```
<select id="myselect"> 
   <option data-url="orange.html">Orange</option>
   //etc...
</select>
```

Example in jQuery:

```
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  location.href=$(this).data('url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add attribute link to each option

```
<SELECT NAME="fruit" id="fruit" onchange="change();" SIZE="4" MULTIPLE >
    <option SELECTED link="#"> Apples</option>
    <option link="#"> Bananas</option>                                                                        
    <option link="#"> Oranges</option>
    <option link="#"> Watermelon</option>
    <option link="#"> Kiwi</option>
</SELECT>
```

and in javascript

```
function change(){
    fruit = document.getElementById('fruit');
    link = fruit.options[fruit.selectedIndex].getAttribute('link');
}
```

and now in `link` is stored link